# Cache 30 thousand objects php

Tags: memcached

Hello I currently have a php site which 30000 images.

Each image has a page containing all data relating to each image.

The site currently has memcache installed.

I need to cache the data for each image. Is it a case where i simple cache an array of image data, i.e. 30k records and then look through this to return the results. I am just unsure whether this would be quicker then querying the database.

Any other suggestions or articles on the best way of implementing caching in php for 30000 pages of image data would be great

Comment: Memcache is basically a key-value store and does not provide any search functionality, it just won't help here. A database with proper indexes will work sufficiently fast with 30k records I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could cache the data with the image name (or other unique identifier) as the key. 
Each image would have it's own key so you can quickly retrieve the data for that image from the cache.

Comment: can the cache become too big tho, if i have 30k cache keys, or do i cache the array and look through the array. Just curious to know when it becomes counter productive

Comment: Determine the top X% most popular images and cache those. If I recall correctly, that's how Wikipedia does it.

Comment: why not cache all data. Is this cause it becomes to slow to query the cache and quicker to query the database

Comment: It's a balancing act. Cache everything and you risk running out of memory, or decreased memory impacting on performance. Only you can determine this by testing.

Comment: Memcache can easily handle 30k keys. As memory is needed it simply removes the older items. How much data would each key have - and how much memory do you have available?

Comment: i need to look into how much available memory there is on the server. If it best to store an array in the memcache and one key then look through the array or 30k seperate memcache keys

Comment: 30k memcache keys. Storing everything in one array in one key would mean that you'd have to retrieve the whole array and look through it every time. That defeats the purpose. memcached is very fast at retrieving the values. A separate key for each image is the way to go.

Comment: am getting this with a single image data MemcachePool::set(): Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: SERVER_ERROR object too large for cache

Comment: How large is the object you are caching? By default there is a 1MB/object limit. Is the data for each image larger than 1mb?

Comment: So that would be an issue. I should have mentioned that limitation before. I believe it is possible to up the max size though. As an aside - that's a lot of data for each image, what are storing with it?

Comment: its all meta data, i.e. albums, user data, user other images etc

Comment: Can you split it up into multiple keys? So if the key name was "image1", make "image1_albums", "image1_user_data" etc... Maybe not ideal, but it could work. That or look into increasing the limit for the cache size.